# How to get the result object from a call inside Result

Tags: swift, rest

I have this code, after making a call to a service

```
switch result {
        case .success(_):
             values = *** Here I want to get the object inside result ***
        case .case .failure(let error):
```

result is

```
result: Result<ProductListModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you did it for failure
either
`case .success(let value):` or `case let .success(value):`
and now you can use value.

```
print(value)
```